# SQL insert with select and hard-coded values

Tags: sql, mysql, insert

For illustration purposes, let's say I have a database Movies(Title, Director, Cost, Profits).

Now I would like to insert a new row into the Movies table based on a director found in another table and then hard coded values.

```
INSERT INTO Movies 
SELECT name 
  FROM Directors 
 WHERE name = 'Lucas';
```

Is how I understand select inserts work but what if I want to use the select as well as pass in hard coded values. So something theoretically like this:

```
INSERT INTO Movies 
VALUES(Star Wars,(SELECT name 
                    FROM Directors 
                   WHERE name='Lucas'), 50000, 1000000);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: if u have to select name [lucas] from director table then wouldn't it be simple if we directly use lucas instead of selecting it from another table?

Comment: @Kool, I assumed that was just an example although, to be honest, I'm not sure of the behaviour if directors _has_ no Lucas (error or insert no rows).

Comment: @paxdiablo, inserts zero rows

Comment: It was a contrived example to get at the general concept I wanted.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Movies (Title, Director, Cost, Profits)
SELECT 'Star Wars', name, 50000, 1000000
FROM Directors WHERE name = 'Lucas'
```

Comment: would be even better if include the fieldnames of movies table too

Comment: @KoolKabin True, but the question wasn't forthcoming with such details

Comment: maybe you should look closer :-)

Answer (score 10):

Because you can specify hardcoded values in the `select` statement, it's probably cleaner to use:

```
insert into movies (title, director, cost, profits)
   select 'Star Wars', name, 50000, 1000000 from directors where name = 'Lucas';
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is possible.  User INSERT .. SELECT syntax. See [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) for more details.  The hard coded values should be in your SELECT query rather than inside the VALUES. E.g.

```
INSERT INTO Movies
SELECT 'Star Wars', name, 50000, 1000000
FROM Directors 
WHERE name = 'Lucas';
```

Answer (score 1):

you have database as Movies(Title, Director, Cost, Profits).
if u want to enter the values in the respective tables then first select the table and then insert values in those tables.