# Copy data into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to copy/append data from one table into another table with same schema in SQL Server?

**Edit:**

let's say there is a query

```
select * 
into table1 
from table2 
where 1=1
```

which creates `table1` with the same schema as well as data as in `table2`.

Is there any short query like this to only copy entire data only into an already existing table?

Comment: Just for complete information, be careful this commands DO NOT copy indexes and triggers of table!
See following post for copy indexes and triggers script:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582852/programmatically-copy-indexes-from-one-table-to-another-in-sql-server

Comment: How to solve this ? `INSERT INTO newTable (col1, col2, col3,col4) values
((SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM oldTable where condition),'string');`

Comment: you can do like 
`INSERT INTO newTable (col1, col2, col3,col4) values ((SELECT column1, column2, column3, 'string' as col4 FROM oldTable where condition))`

Answer (score 432, accepted):

If both tables are truly the same schema:

```
INSERT INTO newTable
SELECT * FROM oldTable
```

Otherwise, you'll have to specify the column names (the column list for `newTable` is optional if you are specifying a value for all columns and selecting columns in the same order as `newTable`'s schema):

```
INSERT INTO newTable (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM oldTable
```

Comment: what if I want to enter `blank data` for some column ??

Comment: @coder it's just a select clause, so you're welcome to put anything in it you want, including explicit `NULL`s, string constants, expressions, or even subqueries.

Comment: why this does not work `INSERT INTO newTable (col1, col2, col3,col4) values
((SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM oldTable where condition),'string');`

Comment: @AbdullahNurum Because your scalar query is selecting more than one column. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141370/sql-insert-with-select-and-hard-coded-values and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254913/sql-select-inside-insert-values

Comment: If both tables present similar schema, but there is a column with 'Identity Specification' on YES, the SQL statement need to enumerate all the columns, except the one with Identity Specification.

Comment: Hi @lc. , My new table Schema and old table  Schema is different. so I want to specify column names to copy the data from one table to another. However, how to copy data of system versioned columns from old table to new table?

Comment: If both tables are identical and have an IDENTITY COLUMN, I turn the destination identity column's property "Identiity Specification/(Is Identity)" to No manually, perform the INSERT/SELECT, and then manually turn the identity back on.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32002876/how-to-copy-data-in-identity-column for details on @Gabriel's case.  Questions could be merged.

Answer (score 36):

Simple way if new table does not exist and you want to make a copy of old table with everything then following works in SQL Server.

```
SELECT * INTO NewTable FROM OldTable
```

Comment: This won't work for Oracle. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472519/oracle-copy-data-to-another-table

Answer (score 24):

This is the proper way to do it:

```
INSERT INTO destinationTable
SELECT * FROM sourceTable
```

Answer (score 18):

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM table2
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable1 (Col1, Col2, Col4)
   SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM MyTable2
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
Insert Into table2
Select * from table1
```

Answer (score 6):

Insert Selected column with condition

```
INSERT INTO where_to_insert (col_1,col_2) SELECT col1, col2 FROM from_table WHERE condition;
```

Copy all data from one table to another with the same column name.

```
INSERT INTO where_to_insert 
SELECT * FROM from_table WHERE condition;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
CREATE TABLE `table2` LIKE `table1`;
INSERT INTO `table2` SELECT * FROM `table1`;
```

the first query will create the structure from `table1` to `table2` and second query will put the data from `table1` to `table2`

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO DestinationTable(SupplierName, Country)
SELECT SupplierName, Country FROM SourceTable;
```

It is not mandatory column names to be same.

Answer (score 2):

**Copy all columns from one table to another table:**

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

**Copy only some columns from one table into another table:**

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

**You can duplicate or "clone" a table's contents by executing:**

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT * FROM original_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

-- for Sql Server users.

if you don't have the new table then you can create the new table with same structure as old table, and also copy data over from old table to the new table. For example:

```
select * into new_table
from old_table;
```

also you can copy the column / table structure, and just some of data. For example:

```
select * into new_table
from old_table 
where country = 'DE';
```