# How to copy data from one table to another "EXCEPT" one field

Tags: mysql, sql

How to INSERT into another table except specific field

e.g

TABLE A

```
ID(auto_inc)    CODE    NAME
1               001     TEST1
2               002     TEST2
```

I want to insert CODE and NAME to another table, in this case TABLE B but except ID because it is auto increment

Note: I don't want to use "INSERT INTO TABLE B SELECT CODE, NAME FROM TABLE A", because I have an existing table with around 50 fields and I don't want to write it one by one

Thanks for any suggests and replies

Comment: Just list the columns.  You can get them from `information_schema.columns` if you don't want to type them.

Comment: You cannot `select *` minus the first column, you have to write the columns out.  Depending on your needs, you could possibly use dynamic sql, but I'd say to map your columns.

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you give me example?

Comment: @sgeddes how can i write it? (map columns)

Comment: if going into an existing table are these inserts only? (i.e. you don't want to update some existing records with this data?)

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the columns using `information_schema.columns`:

```
select group_concat(column_name separator ', ')
from information_schema.columns c
where table_name = 'tableA' and
      column_name <> 'id';
```

This gives you the list.  Then past the list into your code.  You can also use a prepared statement for this, but a prepared statement might be overkill.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done without specifying the columns (excludes the primary key).

This question might help you. [Copy data into another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237623/copy-data-into-another-table)

Answer (score 1):

If this is a one time thing?
If yes, do the insert into tableA (select * from table B)
then Alter the table to drop the column that your dont need.

Comment: that's thinking "outside the box"; occasionally I have trouble with the alter table mechanism, however....

Answer (score 0):

I tried to copy from  a table to another one with one extra field.
source table is TERRITORY_t
* the principle is to create a temp table identical to the source table, adjust column fields of the temp table and copy the content of the temp table to the destination table.

This is what I did:

1. create a temp table called TERRITORY_temp

generate SQL by running export

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TERRITORY_temp` (
  `Territory_Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Territory_Name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Territory_Id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

2. copy over with
   INSERT INTO `TERRITORY_temp` (`Territory_Id`, `Territory_Name`) VALUES
   (1, 'SouthEast'),
   (2, 'SouthWest'),
   (3, 'NorthEast'),
   (4, 'NorthWest'),
   (5, 'Central');

or 
INSERT INTO `TERRITORY_temp`
SELECT * from `TERRITORY_t`

4. add the extra field(s) to match with the new table
5. copy from the temp table to the destination table

INSERT INTO `TERRITORY_new`
SELECT * from `TERRITORY_temp`

Please provide feedback.

Comment: That's now what the OP asked for. They want to skip the ID from the original table. The proper approach is to list out the columns from the information_schema and use this in the select clause.

Comment: Your answer will be much more helpful if you convert *your* use case into the OP's use case, as well as using code formatting. This will make your snippet easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Create stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CopyDataTable

    @SourceTable varchar(255),
    @TargetTable varchar(255),
    @SourceFilter nvarchar(max) = ''

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SourceColumns VARCHAR(MAX)=''
    DECLARE @TargetColumns VARCHAR(MAX)=''
    DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(MAX)=''

    SELECT 
           @SourceColumns = ISNULL(@SourceColumns +',', '') + T.COLUMN_NAME
    FROM 
    ( 
        select name as COLUMN_NAME from sys.all_columns
        where object_id = (select object_id from sys.tables where name = @SourceTable)
        and is_identity = 0
    )T

    SELECT 
           @TargetColumns = ISNULL(@TargetColumns +',', '') + T.COLUMN_NAME
    FROM 
    ( 
        select name as COLUMN_NAME from sys.all_columns
        where object_id = (select object_id from sys.tables where name = @TargetTable)
        and is_identity = 0
    )T


    set @Query = 'INSERT INTO ' + @TargetTable + ' (' + SUBSTRING(@TargetColumns,2 , 9999) + ') SELECT ' + SUBSTRING(@SourceColumns,2 , 9999) + ' FROM ' + @SourceTable + ' ' + @SourceFilter;

    PRINT @Query
    --EXEC(@Query)
    
END
GO
```

2. Step 2. Run stored procedure

   use YourDatabaseName
   exec dbo.CopyDataTable 'SourceTable','TargetTable'
3. Explanations

a) `dbo.CopyDataTable` will transfer all data from `SourceTable` to `TargetTable`, except field with `Identity`

b) You can apply filter when call stored procedure, in order to transfer only row based on criteria

```
exec dbo.CopyDataTable 'SourceTable','TargetTable', 'WHERE FieldName=3'

exec dbo.CopyDataTable 'SourceTable','TargetTable', 'WHERE FieldName=''TextValue'''
```

c) Remove `--` from `--EXEC(@Query) WHEN finish`