# How to copy records from one table to another table, daily in mysql phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin, automation

I have a table in my database named master_table. I want to copy the records from this table to another table named daily_table, everyday at 8 am. 
The records copied everyday should not overwrite the existing records in the daily table. I'm using phpMyAdmin mysql. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: u need to run the cron job

Comment: Yes, write a php script that does that and call that every day at 8am automatically using cron or something like Windows scheduler.

Comment: Check about http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html

Answer (score 1):

If both tables are truly the same schema:

```
INSERT INTO newTable SELECT * FROM oldTable
```

Reference : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237623/copy-data-into-another-table)