# Copy column of table to another table SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to insert all the rows of a column from one table in the schema to to rows in a column of other table in the schema.

As an example:

```
  Table1                    Table2
  ------                    ------

id    numbers            id    figures
--    -------            --    -------
1       35
2       29
3       5
4       3
```

As you can see, Table2 is empty, all the rows from column 'numbers' should be inserted to column 'figures'.

id in Table2 is set on A_I

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237623/copy-data-into-another-table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `INSERT INTO SELECT` like this:

```
INSERT INTO 
Table2(figures)
SELECT numbers from Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Code as follows should suffice:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT numbers = figures 
FROM   table1
```