# How to insert one server environment into another server environment in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

**In my Developement  Environment**

```
Employee Table 
ID, NUMBER (PK)
NAME VARCHAR2(20)
DP_ID NUMBER (FK)
```

**In my Testing Environment**

```
Employee Table 
ID, NUMBER (PK)
NAME VARCHAR2(20)
DP_ID NUMBER (FK)
```

with same structure in my  Developement  Environment  having 3,00000 record .
now i want to insert 3,00000  in my  Testing Environment in oracle .

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Do you want to move all the data from dev to test?  If so, a database link an an `INSERT SELECT` would work.  So would exporting and importing.  If you're asking something else, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237623/copy-data-into-another-table) that may be of some use to you. Also if you're using any program to manage your data, e.g. PHPMyAdmin, they typically have an 'export data as sql statement' option for easy insertion.

Comment: I am asking different Environment.not same environment