# How to copy data in identity column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with an `identity` column in a server and have a other table with same structure in another server.. Now I want to copy all data from one table to other table but I can't help it...

I have already created a linked server..

I use this:

```
insert into [server].[database].[dbo].[table1]
    select *
    from table2
```

I also use this query without identity column in the place of `*`

```
insert into [server].[database].[dbo].[table1]
   select column1, column2
   from table2
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to insert into a second table that also has an identity column, then you need to **explicitly define** the list of columns you're inserting into and omit the `identity` column:

```
insert into [server].[database].[dbo].[table1] (col1, col2)
   select column1, column2
   from table2
```

This way, SQL Server can insert the identity values in the target table as it should

**Update:**

two scenarios:

**(1)** you want to insert the existing values from the identity column from the old table into the new one - in that case, you need to use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON/OFF` in your query:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [192.168.1.6].[audit].[dbo].[tmpDTTransfer] ON 

INSERT INTO [192.168.1.6].[audit].[dbo].[tmpDTTransfer] (id, code, transfer1)
   SELECT  
       id, code, transfer1 
   FROM 
       tmpDTTransfer 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [192.168.1.6].[audit].[dbo].[tmpDTTransfer] OFF
```

**(2)** if you don't want to insert the existing identity values, but just the other columns and let SQL Server assign new identity values in the target table, then you **don't need to use** `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON/OFF` in your query:

```
INSERT INTO [192.168.1.6].[audit].[dbo].[tmpDTTransfer] (code, transfer1)
   SELECT  
       code, transfer1 
   FROM 
       tmpDTTransfer
```

But in any you, you should **always explicitly define** the list of columns to insert into, in your target table.

**DO NOT USE:**

```
INSERT INTO [192.168.1.6].[audit].[dbo].[tmpDTTransfer] 
   .......
```

But instead use

```
INSERT INTO [192.168.1.6].[audit].[dbo].[tmpDTTransfer] (Code, Transfer1)
   .......
```

or

```
INSERT INTO [192.168.1.6].[audit].[dbo].[tmpDTTransfer] (Id, Code, Transfer1)
   .......
```

or whatever you need. Be **explicit** about what you want to insert into!

Comment: my table1 has these three column



id ,Code ,transfer1

Comment: @JeffAtwood: then **select** `Code` and `Transfer1` from your table 1, and make sure to **define** which columns to insert this into in your target table

Comment: i use this but its not work:-



SET IDENTITY_INSERT [192.168.1.6].[audit].[dbo].[tmpDTTransfer] ON
insert into [192.168.1.6].[audit].[dbo].[tmpDTTransfer]
select code,transfer1
from tmpDTTransfer
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT [192.168.1.6].[audit].[dbo].[tmpDTTransfer] OFF

Answer (score 3):

Set [IDENTITY_INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059(v=sql.120).aspx) for table:

```
  SET IDENTITY_INSERT [server].[database].[dbo].[table1] ON
  insert into [server].[database].[dbo].[table1]
  select column1,column2
  from table2
  SET IDENTITY_INSERT [server].[database].[dbo].[table1] OFF
```

Comment: Msg 117, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
The object name '192.168.1.6.audit.dbo.tmpDTTransfer' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.





this is error whith this query.

Comment: SET IDENTITY_INSERT [192.168.1.6].[audit].[dbo].[tmpDTTransfer] ON
insert into [192.168.1.6].[audit].[dbo].[tmpDTTransfer]
select code,transfer1
from tmpDTTransfer
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT [192.168.1.6].[audit].[dbo].[tmpDTTransfer] OFF

Comment: @JeffAtwood it seems, you have two schemas `[audit].[dbo]`. is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to necessarily use SQL script, than you can do it using SQL Server Import and Export Wizard. 
You can read the tutorial [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx).