# Insert columns from another table

Tags: pervasive

I'm not sure if I'm going the right way about this but I want to create another table with an auto increment ID.

I created another table but how do I add the columns from the first table into the new table and an auto increment ID?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy data into another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237623/copy-data-into-another-table)

Comment: Error: Insert value list does not match column list

Comment: I'm assuming you tried `INSERT INTO newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable`, not specifying the columns?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Your tables are not identical, so you want to use the second suggestion from that accepted answer: `INSERT INTO newTable (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM oldTable`

Comment: I tried that too. Error: Invalid column name: 'License'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157504/discussion-between-nathan-hinchey-and-tryingtolearn).

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is the same as copying any table into another table, just be sure not to specify the ID column.

```
INSERT INTO newTable (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM oldTable
```

See also: [Copy data into another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237623/copy-data-into-another-table)