# SQL Server job for copying data from a database to another one

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms-2012

I am amateur in SQL Server jobs or procedures and i need to develop a job to copy data from a database to another one. if you know a little example that can help me to create it, i will really thankfull.

It should be like a function, that someones call the function (by the name) and it automatically copy data from a database to another one.

Comment: 1) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/copy-columns-from-one-table-to-another-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15  2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237623/copy-data-into-another-table  3) https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-copy-tables-from-one-database-to-another-in-sql-server/

Comment: or, in words, use the "SQL Server Export/Import wizard"

Comment: Is this a direct copy or do you want to perform a few modifications before copying the data to new server?

Comment: Is a direct copy, monthly i need to call to the SQL Server job, to copy data from a DB to the another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Expand the SQL Server Agent node and right click the Jobs node in SQL Server Agent and select **'New Job'**
2. In the 'New Job' window enter the name of the job and a description on the **'General'** tab.
3. Select **'Steps'** on the left hand side of the window and click **'New'** at the bottom.
4. In the 'Steps' window **enter a step name and select the database** you want the query to run against.
5. Paste in the **T-SQL command** you want to run into the Command window and click 'OK'.

```
    INSERT INTO newTable
    SELECT * FROM oldTable
```

6. Click on the **'Schedule'** menu on the left of the New Job window and enter the schedule information (e.g. *daily and a time*).
7. Click 'OK' - and that should be it.

Check the animated gif by [S.Mason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2193409/s-mason)

[image]